# Як правильно говорити про час у випадках наприклад «12:43»?

Tags: прийменники, позначення-часу

Я вже читав про це, але мені поки що не зрозуміло, як слід говорити в конкретному випадку. Припустімо, якась подія починається о 12:43, і хтось питає у кого-небудь іншого, коли вона починається. Я знаю, що в російській часто відповіли б «в двенадцать сорок три». Як буде правильно українською? Чи можна сказати «о дванадцятій сорок три»?

Answer (score 2):

Так, «о дванадцятій сорок три» сказати можна. Якщо точність не настільки важлива, можна й інакше відповісти: «(подія починається) за чверть до першої». Див. пов’язане обговорення [тут](https://lingvoforum.net/index.php?topic=84033.0).

Answer (score 1):

Щоб вказати час, використовуємо порядковий числівник жіночого роду + слово “година” в жіночому роді:
14.00 – зараз друга година;
13.00 – зараз перша година.
Щоб сказати, о котрій годині відбудеться якась подія (точний час), використовуємо: о/об + порядковий числівник жіночого роду в місцевому відмінку:
о 12.00 – о дванадцятій годині;
о 17.00 – о п’ятій годині;
об 11.00 – об одинадцятій годині.
Якщо треба лиш приблизно назвати період між двома годинами, тоді слід ставити перед порядковим числівником прийменник на: Я прийду на п’яту годину.
В українській мові годину вказуємо порядковим числівником (сьома, восьма…), а хвилини і секунди - уже кількісним (двадцять п’ять, десять…):
10:10 - десята (година) десять (хвилин);
десять хвилин по десятій;
десять хвилин на одинадцяту.
10.30 - десята (година) тридцять (хвилин);
пів на одинадцяту.
10.40 - десята (година) сорок (хвилин);
за двадцять (хвилин) одинадцята;
двадцять (хвилин) до одинадцятої.

Джерело: https://webpen.com.ua/pages/Antonenko-Davudovich/12_Antonenko-Davidovich_numerals.html